# 3-connected graph- Proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification

> Prove that there is no 3-connected graph with 7 edges.

My solutions:

Let G be a simple, connected graph. $\delta \left ( G \right )$ (minimum degree) for k-connected graph is: $\delta(G)\geq k$. So in our case $\delta(G)\geq 3$.

Let  $\delta(G)= 3$, then according to definition $\left | V\left ( G \right ) \right |> 3$ ( $\left | V\left ( G \right ) \right |$ number of vertices). Let $\left | V\left ( G \right ) \right |= 4$, then  $\left | E\left ( G \right ) \right |=6$.

Does it prove the statement?

Comment: No: what if $|V(G)|>4$? (HINT: What is the sum of the degrees of the vertices of a graph with $7$ edges?)

Comment: When you say, “Let $\delta(G) = 3$”, I think you mean “Suppose that $\delta(G) = 3$.”  *Let* is for assignment, and we can't assign the degree of this given graph.  *Suppose* is for conditional.  But more to the point, you seem to be arguing that if $G$ is 3-connected, then $|E(G)| \geq 6$.  But how does that imply $|E(G) |\neq 7$?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott if $ | V ( G  )  |> 4 $, e.g. $5$, then $ | E ( G )  |=8 $, the sum of the degrees of the vertices for 7 edges is 14. From the previous, does it mean that, if for $| V ( G  )  |> 4 $,  $| E ( G)  |=8$ and for  $| V( G )  |> 3$, $| E ( G )  |=8$, there is no way that  $| E ( G) |=7$, so it is proved?

Comment: @Peter: I don’t see why you think that $|E(G)|=8$ if $G$ has $5$ vertices, or why you think that it’s enough to consider the case of $5$ vertices. Assume that $G$ has $7$ edges, and get a contradiction. As you say, the sum of the degrees of the vertices would be $14$. If there are more than $4$ vertices, what can you say about the average degree of a vertex?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Average degree is $2*|E|/|V|$ .. so in our case the average degree should be $2$ because we have $2*|E|/|V|$=$2*|7|/|V|$=$14/|V|$ and for more then 4 vertices, if we want the number to be integer we need 7 vertices.. so that is a contradiction?

Comment: @Peter: In our case all we know is that the average degree is $\frac{14}{|V|}$. If $|V|>4$, then $|V|\ge 5$, so $\frac{14}{|V|}\le\frac{14}5<3$. This is impossible if $G$ is $3$-connected; why?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott yes, I understand, but the degree of a vertex should be integer, or? That is why I let $| V |=7$.. and it is because minimum degree if a vertex$\geq 3$.. Is that correct?

Comment: @Peter: It’s a little more complicated than that. What you have to realize is that if the average degree is less than $3$, then at least one vertex has degree less than $3$, and that, as you say, is impossible. Alternative, you could avoid dealing with the average degree by observing that if $|V|\ge 5$ and $\delta(G)\ge 3$, then the sum of the degrees must be at least $5\cdot3=15$, and since this is greater than $14$, $G$ cannot have $7$ edges. (You have the right idea; the problem is just to express it clearly.)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott thank you so much, can you post your comment as an answer?

Comment: @Peter: Will do; it’ll take just a few minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that $G$ is a $3$-connected graph with $7$ edges. You’ve shown that $|V(G)|\ge 5$, and we know that $\delta(v)\ge 3$ for each $v\in V$ (since $G$ is $3$-connected), so $\sum_{v\in V}\delta(v)\ge 3\cdot 5=15$, contradicting the fact that $\sum_{v\in V}\delta(v)=2|E(G)|=14$. Therefore no such graph exists.